# docker build stuck on dotnet restore

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a docker image of a .NET 6 project, but is stuck during `dotnet restore` while using `+12GB` of RAM.

My project structure is:

```
- backend/
- frontend/
```

Where I just `cd` in the `backend/` and run `docker build .`

[image]

This is the output of the console currently:

```sh
[+] Building 276.4s (15/19)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.server                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0                                                                           0.6s 
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                        0.6s 
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0@sha256:9ca180a6a0a0ec39209437e5e0986caf17b7d91473d9c34bb6191e47a7b500aa          0.0s 
 => [build-env 1/6] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:ca4344774139fabfb58eed70381710c8912900d92cf879019d2eb52abc307102           0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                           0.2s 
 => => transferring context: 3.69kB                                                                                                         0.2s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED [build-env 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => CACHED [build-env 3/6] COPY *.csproj ./                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [build-env 4/6] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                                    270.2s
```

My csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1705;1591;10102;</NoWarn>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**\node_modules\**;$(DefaultItemExcludes)</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.env" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="BCrypt.Net-Next" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="dotenv.net" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

ARG Config=Debug
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything
COPY . .

# Publish
RUN dotnet publish -c ${Config} -o /app/publish

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

My net usage:
[image: net usage]

This is a pass result (1 hour) building:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, the problem was in my `.csproj`

```xml
 <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.env" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I changed it to:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Include="..\**\*.env" Condition="'$(DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER)' != 'true'" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a different case, I thought my application was stuck on the restore, however it was stuck on the build. You can also add the following to flags to your dotnet restore command as well as your dotnet build command to get more information when your build is running -v diag

```
# RUN dotnet restore "Myproject.Ticketing/Myproject.Ticketing.csproj"
# So instead of just the line at the top, add the -v diag flag like below

RUN dotnet restore -v diag "Myproject.Ticketing/Myproject.Ticketing.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "Myproject.Ticketing.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build -v diag
```

Remember, this is in the Dockerfile. What I did was I first put -v diag on the dotnetrestore and that's when I realized after looking at the output that it was actually passing that stage. Next I removed it from the restore and put the same flag on the build line, this is because there was just a lot of information being output, so I just wanted to limit the output.

Well, the conclusion was that, for me, the last phrase written on the output was

warnaserror+:NU1605 (TaskId:105)

Which after googling gave me

> A dependency package specified a version constraint on a higher version of a package than restore ultimately resolved.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605

So although my application was building and working great in development, there was a library I was depending on that depends on .Net Core 3.1 but yet I am using .Net 6, and the docker container being built is also building on top of .Net 6

Don't ask me how it works, it just did.

> I got the -v flag from reading this article which also helps with the whole hanging problem https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/solving-flaky-dotnet-restore-issue-only-on-docker-failed-to-retrieve-information-cd847573c3f2
>
> For a list of the meanings and options you can put on the dotnet command,
>
> eg -v diag is short for --verbosity diagnostic (so lots of info since you want to diagnose a proble) you can view https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore#options

Answer (score 0):

On the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3338) (probably) made by the poster here, there is a [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3338#issuecomment-995148905) which states the following:

> Because the project is being placed in a directory that is directly under the root of the container, this path causes a scan of the entire container's file system. This slows things down tremendously.

In other words, the `COPY` and `RUN dotnet restore` command are potentially being made in the root of the Docker container, which causes .NET to scan the entire container file system, which causes the `restore` command to "freeze up".

A potential solution is to ensure you are placing the files into a new directory by using the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) instruction.

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj .

RUN dotnet restore
```

Note, that you will need to update subsequent jobs to point to the new path (in the example above, '/app').

Answer (score -2):

In my case the `.csproj` file didn't contain any `<Watch/>` tag but the `dotnet restore` step stuck anyway. I found the solution in this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/3338#issuecomment-1470997484). In Dockerfile, instead of using version 6.0:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
```

I used version 8.0:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
```

Comment: This seems unrelated to the issue at hand - this is changing the .NET version from 6 to 8 and wouldn't appear to actually solve anything

Comment: @MichaelM, I mentioned that my case is not exactly the same as in the accepted answer. But it solved my issue. People come here via search engines looking at the question header. And they can find this response useful. It's not only about .NET version. You can read a little about it [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-multiplatform-container-support/) (Btw, I tried your solution and it didn't help me. Should I downvote it?)

Comment: (1) Unless you are only doing a `dotnet restore` and not building, then your solution will not work without additional changes. You must increase the `<TargetVersion/>` inside your csproj file. So at the minimum, your answer is not sufficiently explanatory.

Comment: (2) Your answer does not answer this question - changing to .NET 8 containers does not stop the `dotnet restore` command from hanging. The links you posted have almost nothing to do with `dotnet restore` and instead have to do with platform targeting. Just because your answer is tangentially related does not make it a good answer

Comment: I will remove the downvote (when possible), but you should provide an explanation as to _why_ this solution works. What was your configuration like that platform changes had any effect? What else did you need to change to get it to work? Rather than posting a link to a comment that links to another comment, explain what those comments are providing in terms of explanation